# Unable to create a file in a certain location on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, permissions, mysql

I'm trying to create a text file as below...

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=11111 database1 << EOF
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE status = 1
INTO OUTFILE '/home/user/feeds/file.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
EOF
```

Which displays an error;

```
ERROR 1 (HY000) at line 1: Can't create/write to file '/home/user/feeds/file.txt' (Errcode: 13)
```

I tried creating the file in `/tmp/file.txt` and it works, but then again I can't move nor delete the file as it says;

```
Operation not permitted
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How & where are you creating the file? Using which user are you trying to do? Please elaborate

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using a bash script. The user is just a user on the system. Where = "INTO OUTFILE '/home/user/feeds/file.txt'".

Comment: Firstly, this doesn't seems like a bash script for me (assuming you have not specificed the #!/bin/bash phrase). And secondly you mean to say that you're trying to execute this bash script with a normal user (which I don't think will work in such case). a bash file should be ended as `filename.sh` & it should start with `#!/bin/bash`. Can you also `cd` into the file location & type `ls -l`, then post the output of the file, pls

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is run fom the *mysql* user. If you want a MySQL script to write into user *user*'s home you need to provide the right permissions to *mysql*. For instance, you can pass the ownership of the `feeds` folder to *mysql*:

`chown mysql:mysql /home/user/feeds`

Or to pass ownership of the text file:

`touch /home/user/feeds/file.txt`

`chown mysql:mysql /home/user/feeds/file.txt`

Comment: It would return the error `ERROR 1086 (HY000) at line 1: File '/home/user/file.txt' already exists`